# Time series benchmarking/reconciliation and revisions - are there methods that minimise revisions?

Tags: time-series, sum, disaggregation

I am using the tempdisagg R package for benchmarking quarterly time series to annual time series from different (more trusted) sources (by temporally disaggragating the annual data using the quarterly data as indicator series).

The time series are sub series and sum series, and these identities should hold after benchmarking, too. I.e. if

```
S = A + B - C,
```

then

```
predict(td(S,...)) = predict(td(A, ...)) + predict(td(B, ...)) - predict(td(C,...)).
```

I have tried the Denton-Cholette and the Chow-Lin-maxlog methods.

This is to be carried out regularly, so ideally I would like a disaggregation method that minimises revisions. I have tried removing up to ten years' worth a data from various time series to see if any method outperforms the other in terms of minimising revisions, but it seems that it depends on a combination of time series volatility and method and I can't reach a conclusion.

It would be possible to use a combination of different methods on the sub series, I guess.

Is there any comprehensive knowledge on benchhmarking and revisions?

I have attached some graphs in an attempt to illustrate the problem. Ideally, we would like to see one line that just changes colour according to the various years of data, as in the first two graphs until about 2015. The black lines in the graphs are the raw data.

PS: I appologise for the sparse tagging. I couldn't find any tags related to the topic such as 'benchmarking' or 'reconciliation'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could also include some translation of the danish text in the plots?

Comment: I deemed it not necessary. The first part says "Checking revisions" in Danish. The rest is in English (method and conversion used). In the first two plots, the conversion is "sum" as is default.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizing revisions" ? Dividing the annual value by 4 has 0 revisions and it's not a good benchmark ^^. IMO, it's better to wonder if your model fits the data well. And if it does, then there is less (bad) revisions.

Comment: If you look at the graphs, it's quite obvious that there ARE revisions. It's because the methods (here, Denton-Cholette snd Chow-Lin-maxlog) are NOT just diving a value by 4. Rather, as described in the post, they're distributing the values of the annual series  along a time series that's as consistent with the quarterly one as possible while summing up to the annual series at annual points. The annual sums of the observed quarterly series does typically not correspond with the observations of the annual series (if they did, there would be no reason to benchmark in the first place).

Comment: I know @SiKiHe. I just said that "minimizing the revisions" doesn't mean a lot for me (if you don't give another constraint). Mainstream denton based temporal disaggregation are quite simple, it's basically having a regression model and smoothing the (eventyally AR1/integrated) residual. So what you need above all is a good fit. If you got a small residual, then the revisions will be small